# A differential equation with a complex variable

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

Consider the differential equation
$$u^{\prime}=p(z)u\quad\text{for}\ u\in{}D,$$
where $p$ is a complex-valued continuous function on the open disc $D\subset\mathbb{C}$.
If $z_{0}\in\overline{D}$, then can we write $$u(z)=u(z_{0})\exp\negthinspace\bigg\{\negthinspace\int_{\gamma}p(\zeta)\mathrm{d}\zeta\bigg\}\quad\text{for}\ u\in\overline{D},$$
where $\gamma$ is a smooth curve starting from $z_{0}$ and ending at $z$?

Is there a reference which I can use for such problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two observations:

1. If $U(z)$ is a solution, it is analytic in $D$, and $p(z)=u'(z)/u(z)$ is the quotient of two analytic functions. Since it is assumed to be continuous, it is locally bounded, so $p$ is also analytic. Thus, if $p$ is not analytic, there are no solutions.
2. If $p$ is continuous, $\int_{\gamma}p(\zeta)\,d\zeta$ depends in general on the curve $\gamma$.

Comment: Professor, my main idea is actually what you have mentioned. I am able to show that there is a solution $\upsilon$ of the DE on some open disc $D$. Then, I say that $\upsilon$ is analytic, which implies analiticity of the coefficient $p$ on $D$. For an analytic $p$, can I write the exponential integral?

Comment: If $p$ is analytic in $D$ it has a primitive $P$, that is, an analytic function $P$ such that $P'=p$. Then $u=c\,u^P$ is a solution for any constant $c$. The primitive $P$ can be written as the line integral, which in that case is independent of the curve $\gamma$.

Comment: I, myself, carried out exactly the same discussion too. What about the choice of $z_{0}$? I mean the DE is satisfied in an open disc $D$, but can I give the solution on the closure $\overline{D}$ by allowing $z_{0}$ to be in $\overline{D}$?

Comment: If $P(z_0)=0$, then the constant $c$ is $u(z_0)$.

Comment: I actually meant if I can pick $z_{0}\in\partial{}D$ (on the boundary of $D$) or not.

Comment: I see. Yes, you can do it, since $p$ is continuous up to the border. Cauchy's theorem applies for any closed curve contained in the closure os $D$.